# If $(\mathbb{Z}, +) \cong (C_\infty, \cdot)$, then $\exists K$ such that $K \trianglelefteq C_\infty$ and $K \cong 2\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism

If $(\mathbb{Z}, +) \cong (C_\infty, \cdot)$, then does there exists a normal subgroup from $C_\infty$ (call it $K$) such that $K \cong 2\mathbb{Z}$?

I tried the following:

If $q \in C_\infty$, then $\langle q^2 \rangle := \{q^{2k} | k \in \mathbb{Z}\} \le C_\infty$.

Let $\beta: 2\mathbb{Z} \to \langle q^2 \rangle$ such that $\beta (m) = m^2$.

Unfortunately, this is not a homomorphism.

*Important to note*: This is just a curious question, **NOT** a homework.

Any hints will help.

## EDIT

I think it'll be $\beta (2) = q^2$, where $q \in C_\infty$. Is that correct?

Comment: You’re right. If $C_\infty = \langle x \rangle$, then the map $\beta \colon 2\Bbb Z \to \langle x^2 \rangle$ given by $\beta(m) = x^m$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: **If** they were isomorphic, then the image of $2\mathbb{Z}$ under any particular isomorphism would be a desired subgroup. The map would send $2k$ to $q^{2k}$, where $q$ is whatever the isomorphism you start with sends $1$.